# How to mix variable sequence length and variable batch size in RNN

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to train a RNN-Classifier with a training set that has variable length, I've read around and the suggested solution is to do bucketing on the training data and then feed batches out of each bucket and exit the RNN on certain sequence_length, however the results from this process vs just trimming the input sequences to length 10 is extremely worse and my loss function and accuracy move up and down erratically

**Some more information:**

1. I have variable batch size because some times there's not enough samples of a certain sequence length in a bucket
2. A sequence is a series of words converted into word embeddings
3. If I have a bucket of sequences of length 4, the batch would be of size max_seq_length padding everything on the right with vectors full of 0's
4. batches have the following shape (batch_size,number_steps,embedding_dimensions)

batch(128,48,100)
sequence_length = 4
classes(128,188)

batch(128,48,100)
sequence_length = 8
classes(128,188)

...

batch(30,48,100)
sequence_length = 40
classes(30,188)

5. I feed the sequence_length as the early_stop variable to my RNN

What is the best way to mix variable sequence length with variable bath size?

My Graph:

```
# Network Parameters
n_input = embeddings_dim # word embeddings dimensions : 100
n_steps = max_seq_len # timesteps = maximum sequence length in my training = 47
n_classes = total_labels # total classes = 188

graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    # tf Graph input
    x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_steps, n_input])
    # Tensorflow LSTM cell requires 2x n_hidden length (state & cell)
    istate = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 2*n_hidden])
    y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_classes])
    #at what step we should read out the value of the RNN
    early_stop = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
    tf.scalar_summary('early_stop', early_stop)
    # Define weights
    weights = {
        'hidden': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden])), # Hidden layer weights
        'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden, n_classes]))
    }
    biases = {
        'hidden': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden])),
        'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
    }
    def RNN(_X, _istate, _weights, _biases):
        # input shape: (batch_size, n_steps, n_input)
        _X = tf.transpose(_X, [1, 0, 2])  # permute n_steps and batch_size
        # Reshape to prepare input to hidden activation
        _X = tf.reshape(_X, [-1, n_input]) # (n_steps*batch_size, n_input)
        # Linear activation
        _X = tf.matmul(_X, _weights['hidden']) + _biases['hidden']
        # Define a lstm cell with tensorflow
        lstm_cell = rnn_cell.LSTMCell(n_hidden, forget_bias=0.25)
        # Split data because rnn cell needs a list of inputs for the RNN inner loop
        _X = tf.split(0, n_steps, _X) # n_steps * (batch_size, n_hidden)
        # Get lstm cell output
        outputs, states = rnn.rnn(lstm_cell, _X, 
                                  initial_state=_istate, 
                                  sequence_length=early_stop)
        # Linear activation
        # Get inner loop last output
        return tf.matmul(outputs[-1], _weights['out']) + _biases['out']

    pred = RNN(x, istate, weights, biases)
    # Define loss and optimizer
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(pred, y)) # Softmax loss
    global_step = tf.Variable(0, name='global_step', trainable=False)
    learning_rate_2 = tf.train.exponential_decay(learning_rate, global_step, 300, 0.96, staircase=True)
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate_2).minimize(cost) # Adam Optimizer
    # Evaluate model
    correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred,1), tf.argmax(y,1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))
```

My Training loop:

```
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()    
    sess.run(init)
    step = 1
    while step * batch_size < training_iters:
        #batch_xs = batch_xs.reshape((batch_size, n_steps, n_input))
        batch_xs, batch_ys, batch_sl = train_batches.next()        
        ins_batch_size = len(batch_xs)
        # Fit training using batch data
        summ ,acc = sess.run([merged,optimizer], feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y: batch_ys,
                                       istate: np.zeros((ins_batch_size, 2*n_hidden)),
                                        early_stop:batch_sl})
        train_writer.add_summary(summ, step)
        if step % display_step == 0:
            # Calculate batch accuracy
            acc = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y: batch_ys,
                                                istate: np.zeros((ins_batch_size, 2*n_hidden)),
                                                early_stop:batch_sl})
            # Calculate batch loss
            loss = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y: batch_ys,
                                             istate: np.zeros((ins_batch_size, 2*n_hidden)),
                                             early_stop:batch_sl})
            print( "Iter " + str(step*batch_size) + ", Minibatch Loss= " + "{:.6f}".format(loss) + \
                  ", Training Accuracy= " + "{:.5f}".format(acc))
        step += 1
    print( "Optimization Finished!")
    test_data,test_label, test_sl = test_batches.next()
    test_len = len(test_data)  
    print( "Testing Accuracy:", sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: test_data, y: test_label,
                                                             istate: np.zeros((test_len, 2*n_hidden)),
                                                             early_stop:test_sl}))
```

Comment: I'm curious if you ever managed to come up with a solution to this?